# How to make the input=text field readonly in JSP if details are coming from the backend

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a requirement in which if the user is logged in, i fetch the details from the session and diplay the required details on JSP like his name, email etc. The same functionality, user can do if he is not logged in. In that case I show blank fields and user can enter the details. Now the requirement is, if user is logged in, he should not be allowed to update/modify his detials. Below is my JSP

```
<form:form commandName="Chat" id="Chat" data-widget="form" onsubmit="return false">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td><label><spring:message code="label.chat.name" /></label></td><td><form:input data-validation="[required allowspecialchr]" data-validation-tip="true" maxlength="40" path="name" id="name" placeholder=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><spring:message code="label.chat.email" /></label></td><td><form:input data-validation="[required email]" data-validation-tip="true" path="email" id="email" placeholder=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><spring:message code="label.chat.mobileNo" /></label></td><td><form:input data-validation="[required number]" data-validation-tip="true" path="mobileNo" id="mobileNo" placeholder=""/></td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

Someone plz guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form:input>` element has an attribute called `disabled`.
Once the user is logged in just make it true.

Not good with javascript, but take the below code as hint:-

```
function disablefield()
{
if ( document.getElementById('name').value == '' ||  document.getElementById('name').value == null){
document.getElementById('name').disabled = true;
}
}
```

If the page is loaded with empty name text field that means, user need to enter the value for this field. But if the page is loaded with some value in name field other than null or blank that means, you can disable this field as user is already logged in.

Comment: and if you really want it to look spiffy have a logic statement that chooses a column to render.  One column with the input field and the other without.

Comment: @Amit Bhati : Didnt understood. How to make disabled = true when user is logged in